# Finding Missions

Tags: x-rebirth

I am at a point where money is an issue. As a result, I need to start doing side missions for some extra gold. Problem is, other than flying around each station with scrupulous care and looking for the missions, I don't know a way of getting missions.

Do we really have to spend so long just looking for a mission?

If not, how do I find them?

Comment: I think you can contact people from space by getting close to the station, but I do not know if it is only valid for people you can hire.

Comment: I thought that's what I said I was doing....

Comment: I did not play rebirth yet but in the previous installments trading was the best way to make money. Well it takes money to make money, with trading especially. But eventually you can build your own stations and make tons of credits.

Comment: @MennoGouw in Rebirth, the best way to make money is to use long range scanning to collect crates that magically appear around you, then sell the contents.

Comment: @kotekzot Weird...

Comment: No you said initially that you went through the station so it was unclear if you docked and walked through them or if you used your comms. Anyway the game is pretty broken, you will earn 10x to 20x more money per hour by scanning for crates.

Comment: @BlueTrin Ah OK, any zones in particular? I once activated my station scanning thing but had no idea what to do with it, nothing happened. Hopefully long range scanners will be more obvious. Thanks.

Comment: @MennoGouw In X2 I agree, but in X3 I found that doing combat missions was tones faster. In X3AP stock exchange wasn't bad either. Main problem for me was the time I had to spend going from one sector to another to find a mission worthy of my bother.